# CheckBoxList move selected files to direction

Tags: delphi, checkboxlist

so I have a little problem, my program finds and writes specific files (for example Mp3, wmv and etc) to a CheckBoxList, then I want to select some or all of the files to transfer those files to directory of my choosing. The problem is I dont know how can I move ONLY the selected files?

Heres a bit of code:

```
procedure TfrMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName : String;
begin
dirName := Edit3.Text;
  CreateDir(dirName);
if DirectoryExists(dirName) then MoveFile(PChar(Path), PChar(DirName));
end;

procedure TfrMain.CheckBox2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if CheckBox2.Checked = true then CheckListBox1.SelectAll;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a loop like `for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count - 1 do if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then DoWhateverWithTheItem(CheckListBox1.Items[i]);` you can determine if an item is checked and then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list, and then test whether or not each item is checked.

```
for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count-1 do
  if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then 
    // do something with the item
```

Comment: Again, for some reason @TLama prefers to write answers in comments. But questions need answers, and so here it is. It would have been far better if TLama had just answered the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now I have a problem with moving. How should I move item for example from the Path it's in to another Directory?

Now I run `procedure TfrMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName : String;
  i: integer;
begin
dirName := Edit3.Text;
  CreateDir(dirName);
if DirectoryExists(dirName) then
    for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count-1 do
  if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then MoveFile(PChar(Path),PChar(DirName));
   end;`but it dosen't do anything.

Comment: You are not checking for errors. Presumably MoveFile fails. If you want to find out why, read the docs for MoveFile and check for errors as described. Also, I note that the call to MoveFile does not use i. Same parameters each time. That seems wrong. And the second param to MoveFile must not exist already as per the docs. That's not the case here. Anyway, you can debug this.